# Intercepting system calls at user-level without LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, system-calls

In my program, I want to intercept every system call at user-level within the same process (I don't want to use a separate process such as `ptrace` or a tool such as `strace`). I also don't want to use LD_PRELOAD. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think `LD_PRELOAD` can be used to intercept system calls anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Use C macros. It works like this:

1. Create a header file which defines a macro for each system call that you want to track. Example: `open()`

   ```
   #define open(path,flags,mode)  mySpecialOpen(path,flags,mode)
   ```
2. Create a library which contains the `mySpecial*()` functions which forward the calls to the syscall. Compile the library without the header file.
3. Compile your code (and all libraries that you use) with the header file above. Link with the library.

Comment: But this will not catch hand-coded (i.e., inline assembly) system calls, which a tool like `strace` *does* catch. Also, unless you recompile `libc`, all system calls made through standard library functions are not caught either.

Comment: @Job: As I said: "and all libraries that you use". You know a better solution? OP doesn't want to use any of the official tools; they do a proper job. Anything else has to have some drawbacks.

Comment: Yes, I know but I was merely pointing out two of those drawbacks of your solution. As for a better solution, obviously I don't have one as I would have posted it then:-) I was thinking using some kind of trick to use `ptrace` to trace your own process instead of a child but I guess that won't be possible.

Comment: Yeah :-) If he wanted to track normal library functions, I'd have suggested to change the symbol names in the .o files or maybe mess with the linker.

Comment: see https://lastlog.de/blog/posts/creative_packaging_in_nixpkgs.html as an example how to use LD_PRELOAD. another nice example is this: https://lastlog.de/blog/posts/overwriting_glibc_library_functions.html